# React Native - Orientation locked; can I still get the sensor's orientation?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app which is designed to run in portrait mode. The orientation is locked via the manifest:

```
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

I need to add the ability to take photos which I've done using `react-native-camera`.

The problem is, I can't get the orientation to change when taking photos since it is locked to portrait.

Is there a way to allow orientation to change in a particular view (ie camera container) so that the camera can detect the correct orientation?

I'm thinking maybe the following is possible:

1. request orientation directly from sensor
2. a new activity without the orientation locked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I used React-Native-Orientation : https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation.

You shouldn't lock the orientation in manifest, instead you u can lock every screen to portrait mode using this lib. Use `lockToPortrait()`

And for the screens u need to rotate just use unlockAllOrientations or `lockToLandscape()`

API is great but the problem is u need to do it for every screen .. seems kind of overkill if you have a lot of screens.. but things works great

**Additional Tip**

Doing this in every screen is going to hectic & very hard to manage. 
What i did was modularize my navigation functions to a single class. I

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

export const navigateToMainScreen=()=>{
  determineOrientation("Main");
  this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
}

const determineOrientation=(screenName)=>{
  // ur logic
  if(true){
      Orientation.lockToPortrait();
   }
  else{
   Orientation.lockToLandscape();
   }
}
```

Comment: Screen means something like a root view a container class (React navigation) .. see updated answer

Comment: thanks, upvoted but i'll leave question open for a little bit.