# How to handle Device Orientations in Android React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on an application that needs to handle multiple device orientations such as Landscape & Portrait.

I have subscribed to `Dimensions` event listener as shown below in `componentDidMount`

```
Dimensions.addEventListener("change", this.handler);
```

and I am also unregistering the `eventListener` in `ComponentDidUnMount()` as shown below,

```
Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", this.handler.bind(this));
```

Now what happens is, When I navigate to a different screen from the App Root Component and change the device orientation, the App refreshes and navigates to the Root Component instead of remaining in the same screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `componentWillUnmount` and please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Orientation locked; can I still get the sensor's orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145764/react-native-orientation-locked-can-i-still-get-the-sensors-orientation)